# c# winforms : show static html modal dialog with or without webbrowser

Tags: c#, html, winforms

My need is to show some boring long texts (scrollable) at startup of click once deployed application.
So I have now a web browser that displays the text styled with static html.

```
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            wb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            wb.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(514, 447);
            wb.TabIndex = 0;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;

            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = "MyApp.Status.html";

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();                
                wb.DocumentText = result;
            }
```

Thought it does the need, its not good looking as expected. What I am trying, is to show a html modal dialog looking like this example:

[image]

*So I need to make web browser form transparent and remove the scroll bars and have my own close or move events but still render scrollable contents or any other way to customize this like widget things but in a winform.*

I am not sure this question is appropriate but I hope someone might had tried it already. I can understand C# but do not know much about this rendering objects.

Comment: you could try with https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I am going through the source now and will soon revert to you.

Comment: Hi @AntonioBakula, the HtmlPanel mentioned in the link looks good source for my need. Just need to know if the Html added has any small javascripts like close or scroll functions will it throw any error, cause I good find any reference.

Comment: as far as I know HtmlRenderer doesn't support JavaScript

Comment: Yes, I was  going through discussions and it seems so. But anyway I right now working a sample with it and hoping to make something better. I am also searching for real examples of this being used. Thanks for your guidance.